# Getting Data from Facebook using R

Tags: facebook, r

Hi Using R i am trying to get some Data from Facebook. when i use this command`me <- getUsers("me", token=fb_outh)`[image] i'll get the details about myself. I am getting a result which i have uploaded as an image, Everything is fine except that Likes and Category, as they have values as NA. So if anyone has some previous experience on working on this ,please explain why it is coming as NA for those two values and what it is representing, as I have many pages liked.

Comment: Entering `?NA` gets you the help files. So `NA` means *‘Not Available’ / Missing Values*. Category and Likes are no user profile info.

Comment: @lukeA : Thanks, any idea what Likes and Category represent. I didnt get your second part, what do you mean `no user profile info`.

Comment: I guess it's page category and number of page likes. Can't verify as Rfacebook auth crashes in Rgui on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure you use teh most recent version? As @lukeA says, category and likes are normally part of the page info and not the user

Comment: @Tobi : I am using R version 3.0.1.. Will it be a problem.. and By saying `page info ` which page you are referring , Pages which i have liked .

Comment: I meant RFacebook, not R itself. For informatin on Pages, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: @Tobi: Thnk u... Got it